# Amcharts guides

Tags: javascript, amcharts

When I add the `guides` into `valueAxesSettings` but it doesn't work even I choose `valueAxesSettings` into `valueAxes`. 
Furthermore, what the difference between `valueAxesSettings` and `valueAxes`, as the reference said `If you change a property after the chart is initialized, you should call stockChart.validateNow() method in order for it to work.`? what does it mean?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>My first stock chart</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="amcharts/style.css" type="text/css">

<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amstock.js"></script>

<style>
    #chartdiv {
        width: 100%;
        height: 500px;
        font-size: 11px;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
        AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
            "type": "stock",
            "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD",
            "dataSets": [ {
                "dataProvider": [ {
                    "date": "2011-06-01",
                    "val": 10
                }, {
                    "date": "2011-06-02",
                    "val": 11
                }, {
                    "date": "2011-06-03",
                    "val": 12
                }, {
                    "date": "2011-06-04",
                    "val": 11
                }, {
                    "date": "2011-06-05",
                    "val": 10
                }, {
                    "date": "2011-06-06",
                    "val": 11
                }, {
                    "date": "2011-06-07",
                    "val": 13
                }, {
                    "date": "2011-06-08",
                    "val": 14
                }, {
                    "date": "2011-06-09",
                    "val": 17
                }, {
                    "date": "2011-06-10",
                    "val": 13
                } ],
                "fieldMappings": [ {
                    "fromField": "val",
                    "toField": "value"
                } ],
                "categoryField": "date"
            } ],

            "panels": [ {

                "legend": {},

                "stockGraphs": [ {
                    "id": "graph1",
                    "valueField": "value",
                    "type": "line",
                    "title": "MyGraph",
                    "fillAlphas": 0
                } ]
            } ],

            "panelsSettings": {
                "startDuration": 1
            },

            "categoryAxesSettings": {
                "dashLength": 5
            },

            "valueAxesSettings": {
                "dashLength": 13,
                "guides": {
                    "value": 10,
                    "tovalue": 12,
                    "lineColor": "#CC0000",
                    "lineAlpha": 1,
                    "fillAlpha": 0.2,
                    "fillColor": "#CC0000",
                    "dashLength": 2,
                    "inside": true,
                }
            },

            "chartScrollbarSettings": {
                "graph": "graph1",
                "graphType": "line",
                "position": "bottom"
            },

            "chartCursorSettings": {
                "valueBalloonsEnabled": true
            },

            "periodSelector": {
                "periods": [ {
                    "period": "DD",
                    "count": 1,
                    "label": "1 day"
                }, {
                    "period": "DD",
                    "selected": true,
                    "count": 5,
                    "label": "5 days"
                }, {
                    "period": "MM",
                    "count": 1,
                    "label": "1 month"
                }, {
                    "period": "YYYY",
                    "count": 1,
                    "label": "1 year"
                }, {
                    "period": "YTD",
                    "label": "YTD"
                }, {
                    "period": "MAX",
                    "label": "MAX"
                } ]
            }
        } );
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you change the properties after the chart is initialized, you need to call validateNow() so that the graph is redrawn using your new (changed) settings. You cal also call validateData() but it is optional.

Comment: To expand on @Anurag's comment, you use `validateData` when you change your chart's data. `validateNow` doesn't handle that by default unless you set the first parameter to true, e.g. `validateNow(true, false)` is the equivalent of `validateData()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`valueAxesSettings` is a global version of `valueAxes` - anything you set in `valueAxesSettings` will be applied to all stock panels' `valueAxes` objects. If you want to override or set a specific setting in one of your panels' valueAxes, you can set a `valueAxes` inside the panel:

```
"panels": [{
  "valueAxes":[{
    //settings specific to this panel
  }],
  // ...
}, {
  "valueAxes": [{
    //settings specific to this panel
  }]
}
```

The `guides` property is an array. You're setting it as a single object, which is incorrect. Also, the property is called `toValue`, not "tovalue" - the casing is important. Here's the corrected `valueAxesSettings` object:

```
  "valueAxesSettings": {
    "dashLength": 13,
    "guides": [{
      "value": 10,
      "toValue": 12,
      "lineColor": "#CC0000",
      "lineAlpha": 1,
      "fillAlpha": 0.2,
      "fillColor": "#CC0000",
      "dashLength": 2,
      "inside": true
    }]
  },
```

Demo:

```js
AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "stock",
  "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD",
  "dataSets": [{
    "dataProvider": [{
      "date": "2011-06-01",
      "val": 10
    }, {
      "date": "2011-06-02",
      "val": 11
    }, {
      "date": "2011-06-03",
      "val": 12
    }, {
      "date": "2011-06-04",
      "val": 11
    }, {
      "date": "2011-06-05",
      "val": 10
    }, {
      "date": "2011-06-06",
      "val": 11
    }, {
      "date": "2011-06-07",
      "val": 13
    }, {
      "date": "2011-06-08",
      "val": 14
    }, {
      "date": "2011-06-09",
      "val": 17
    }, {
      "date": "2011-06-10",
      "val": 13
    }],
    "fieldMappings": [{
      "fromField": "val",
      "toField": "value"
    }],
    "categoryField": "date"
  }],

  "panels": [{

    "valueAxes": [{

    }],

    "legend": {},

    "stockGraphs": [{
      "id": "graph1",
      "valueField": "value",
      "type": "line",
      "title": "MyGraph",
      "fillAlphas": 0
    }]
  }],

  "panelsSettings": {
    "startDuration": 1
  },

  "categoryAxesSettings": {
    "dashLength": 5
  },

  "valueAxesSettings": {
    "dashLength": 13,
    "guides": [{
      "value": 10,
      "toValue": 12,
      "lineColor": "#CC0000",
      "lineAlpha": 1,
      "fillAlpha": 0.2,
      "fillColor": "#CC0000",
      "dashLength": 2,
      "inside": true
    }]
  },

  "chartScrollbarSettings": {
    "graph": "graph1",
    "graphType": "line",
    "position": "bottom"
  },

  "chartCursorSettings": {
    "valueBalloonsEnabled": true
  },

  "periodSelector": {
    "periods": [{
      "period": "DD",
      "count": 1,
      "label": "1 day"
    }, {
      "period": "DD",
      "selected": true,
      "count": 5,
      "label": "5 days"
    }, {
      "period": "MM",
      "count": 1,
      "label": "1 month"
    }, {
      "period": "YYYY",
      "count": 1,
      "label": "1 year"
    }, {
      "period": "YTD",
      "label": "YTD"
    }, {
      "period": "MAX",
      "label": "MAX"
    }]
  }
});
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  font-size: 11px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amstock.js"></script>

<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Regarding `validateNow`, if you change a property in your stock chart object, you need to call validateNow to redraw the chart with your new settings. `validateData` is primarily used when you make changes to your  dataSets/dataProvider.